# what is the significance of @tf.function in neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning deep neural networks (beginner level). What is the use of `@tf.function` in tensorflow?
for example

```
@tf.function
def add(a,b):
c=tf.add (a,b)
print(c)
return(c)
```

could anyone please explain how this way of coding helps to create a network

Comment: What do you know about `tf.function`?

Comment: tf. function is the one that creates nodes where computation occurs, where weights and biases were generated

Comment: that's my understanding, don't know whether this is correct or not

Comment: special edition of normal function written in python

Comment: Ok, so you know more about tf than I do, but you need to investigate python decorators.

Comment: You need to search for Graph Execution vs Eager Execution.

Comment: maybe these link : [When to utilize tf.function](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/13), [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55279561/1740577), [link_3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55279561/1740577) help you.

Answer (score 0):

**tf.function** converts the function into a callable `TensorFlow graph` where the tensor computations are executed as a TensorFlow graph(`tf.Graph`).
 "Graphs are data structures that contain a set of `tf.Operation` objects, which represent units of computation; and `tf.Tensor` objects, which represent the units of data that flow between operations". 
**tf.function** allows you to switch from eager execution to graph execution which enables the benefits of graph mode - like portability outside python for deployement and provides better performance(faster).

Please refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) for more information on **tf.function**.